# Average number of transactions per user per day

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe of transactions:

```
user_id mcc_code    currency_rk transaction_amt transaction_dttm    transaction_date
```

I want to know mean of count transactions by user_id by day, how can I achieve this? I think I need mark continues ranges of dates and groupby on it (because df sorted by user_id).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume your dataframe is named `df`, writing

```py
new_df = df.group_by(["user_id", "day"]).loc[:, whatever_transaction_is].transform("count")
```

will give you the count of transaction by user by day. Taking mean of `new_df` will lead to your desired output.

Comment: Thanks ! transactions.groupby(["user_id", "transaction_date"])['currency_rk'].count().groupby(['user_id']).mean() gave me answer

Answer (score 2):

Answer:

```
transactions.groupby(["user_id", "transaction_date"])['currency_rk'].count().groupby(['user_id']).mean()
```